# How can I get a DropDownList selected value and send it to the controller in ASP.NET MVC 4 and using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, aurigma

I did many searches about getting the selected value in DropDownList to send it to the controller using MVC 4, and I found something like that: Request.Form["id"] but they didn't meet my needs.
I have this form:

```
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDTYPE, "TYPES")
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.DropDownList("IDTYPE", String.Empty)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDTYPE)
                        </div>

                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDFLIGHT, "FLIGHTS")
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.DropDownList("IDFLIGHT", String.Empty)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDFLIGHT)
                            @Html.ActionLink("Add New flight","Create","Flight",null,new{@style="font-size:16px;", @class="popup"})
                        </div>
```

I don't want to send data to the controller using the Post Method in the form, but using the folowing Script which is for a plug-in named Aurigma used to upload images and to call an action in the Controller.
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var uploader = $au.imageUploaderFlash({
            id: 'Uploader1',
            licenseKey: '77FF4-00485-962F7-E117E-11414-86DBBB',
            folderProcessingMode: 'Upload',
            restrictions: { fileMask: '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp' },
            messages: { fileNameNotAllowed: 'You can add only images.' },
            width: '100%',
            height: '400px',
            converters: [
           { mode: '*.*=SourceFile' }
            ],
            uploadSettings: {
                actionUrl: '@Url.Action("Ajouter", "Image")'
    }
});
uploader.writeHtml();
```

So, I want to get the id of the selected value in the two DropDownLists IDFLIGHT and IDTYPE and pass it in the actionURL. So, I want to do something like that:

```
actionUrl: '@Url.Action("Ajouter", "Image", new { IdFlight = "id for flight", IdType = "id for type"})'
```

and here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Ajouter(int idflight, int idtype)
    {
        for (int i = 0;
                i < Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["PackageFileCount"]);
                i++)
        {
            if (Request.Form["File0Mode_" + i] != "sourceFile")
                throw
                  new Exception("Uploader expects to send original files.");
            HttpPostedFileBase sourceFile;
            sourceFile = Request.Files["File0_" + i];

            Char[] sepDCap = { '_', '.' };
            String[] data = sourceFile.FileName.Split(sepDCap);
            string Jour = data[1];
            string Mois = data[2];
            string Annee = data[3];

            string dateCreat = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Char[] sepTDate = { '-', '/',' ' };
            String[] dateCr = dateCreat.Split(sepTDate);
            string Jourdc = dateCr[0];
            string Moisdc = dateCr[1];
            string Anneedc = dateCr[2];

            string pathToCreate = "~/Uploads/" + Anneedc + "/" + Moisdc + "/" + Jourdc;
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate));
            }
            string dir = Server.MapPath(pathToCreate);

            sourceFile.SaveAs(dir + "/" + sourceFile.FileName);

            DateTime dateCapt = Convert.ToDateTime(Jour + "-" + Mois + "-" + Annee);
            double latitude = Convert.ToDouble(data[4]);
            double altitude = Convert.ToDouble(data[5]);
            string pathImage = pathToCreate;
            double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(data[6]);

            IMAGES img=new IMAGES();

            img.IDFLIGHT = idflight;
            img.IDTYPE = idtype;                
            img.DATECAPTURE = dateCapt;
            img.LATITUDE = latitude;
            img.ALTITUDE = altitude;
            img.PATHIMAGE = pathImage;
            img.CREATED = Convert.ToDateTime(dateCreat);
            img.LONGITUDE = longitude;

            ImageService imgSce = new ImageService();
            imgSce.create(img);
        }
        Response.Write("Upload Complete");
        return null;
    }
```

thank you !

Comment: This work?

    '@Url.Action("Ajouter", "Image/"id for flight"/"id for type"})'

And your controller action has two properties for the IdFlight and IdType -- or a 'string id' that you parse?

Comment: Please show your controller ?

Comment: Try this actionUrl: '@Url.Action("Ajouter", "Image", new { IdFlight = "id for flight", IdType = "id for type",null})'

Comment: Mr Paul, actually I have to do @Url.Action("Ajouter/"id for flight"/"id for type", "Image"})'. but it doesn't work. The problem is how to retrieve the id of selected velue of flights and types

Comment: Mr Shaikh, The problem is how to retrieve the id of selected velue of flights and types and put it there. I did that Request.Form["IDFLIGHT"] but it doesn't work !!

Comment: Any seggestion please, I'm still waiting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Url.Action()` is razor code and parsed on the server before you pass it to the view. To build the url based on the selected values your dropdown lists, use

```
 actionUrl: '@Url.Action("Ajouter", "Image")' + '?idflight=' + $('#IDFLIGHT').val() + '&idtype=' + $('#IDTYPE').val()
```

Comment: Thank you the code you gave me seems correct, but it gives me this error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined !! I have already this reference <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: The error means that jquery-{version}.js` is NOT loaded. Possibly you have your script declared before jquery or you have duplicate scripts

Comment: thank you so much. I will look for the error depending to what you said :)